# CSV parser in C++ doesn't read the first element

Tags: c++, csv, boost-tokenizer

I extracted this piece of code to parse a CSV file, however it doesn't read the first element for the first n-1 rows. I can't figure it out why, and when I copy the data into a new empty file and save it as CSV file, the error disappears and it works fine. Here are the links for the [original](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rg3xhdqle96rux1/example_file.csv?dl=0) (error happens) and the [copied](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ejduf1caju0r6ql/test.csv?dl=0) (error doesn't happen) CSV file. Could you please help me as why this is happening?

Thank you.

```
#include <boost/tokenizer.hpp>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    using namespace std;

    if (argc != 2)
    {
        cerr << "Usage: " << argv[0] << " <csv file>" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    vector< vector<string> > csv_values;

    fstream file(argv[1], ios::in);

    if (file)
    {
        typedef boost::tokenizer< boost::char_separator<char> > Tokenizer;
        boost::char_separator<char> sep(",");
        string line;

        while (getline(file, line))
        {
            Tokenizer info(line, sep);   // tokenize the line of data
            vector<string> values;

            for (Tokenizer::iterator it = info.begin(); it != info.end(); ++it)
            {
                // convert data into double value, and store
                values.push_back(it->c_str());
            }

            // store array of values
            csv_values.push_back(values);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cerr << "Error: Unable to open file " << argv[1] << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    // display results
    cout.precision(1);
    cout.setf(ios::fixed,ios::floatfield);

    for (vector< vector<string> >::const_iterator it = csv_values.begin(); it != csv_values.end(); ++it)
    {

        const vector<string>& values = *it;

        for (vector<string>::const_iterator it2 = values.begin(); it2 != values.end(); ++it2)
        {
            cout << *it2 << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Only difference is empty line at the end of copied file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New lines in your orginal file ends with a [carriage return](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return), which is read by your code with last varible in the line, and then printed. So first line is printed like this

```
1 2 3 4 5\r
```

and then you print space, which is printed at the beginning of the line, covering "1".

You could easily see that in debugger :)

Comment: Thank you! This was the first time I heard about carriage return, now I know! :)